# Extjs 6.2 Cannot resolve directFn QueryDatabase.getResults

Tags: php, mysql, extjs, proxy

I have performed all the steps from [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/guides/backend_connectors/direct/mysql_php.html)

The only difference in my setup is I have created the app using: `sencha generate app -ext DirectApp E:\xampp\htdocs\extjs_practice\extjs_cmd\DirectApp`

Because I'm not using licensed version so far.

After completing all the steps when I refresh the webpage, grid is empty and in console its showing following ERROR:

```
Ext.data.proxy.Direct.resolveMethods(): Cannot resolve directFn QueryDatabase.getResults
```

Comment: Probably, you are not including api.php in your application. Double check the instructions under "Updating app.json" and that your api.php file is working properly.

Comment: I have double check and all the stuff is same as per sencha documentation: Here is my app.json modifications.

"js": [
        {
            "path": "php/api.php",
            "remote": true
        },
        {
            "path": "app.js",
            "bundle": true
        }
     ],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I have fixed the error by overriding api.php and router.php from Kitchen sink example files.
- In the config.php file added error_reporting(0);
- In the router.php after line 12 added $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = file_get_contents("php://input");
- In the app root folder need to run 'sencha app build'.